# How do I solve the triac error in the LTspice program?

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, ltspice, simulation, triac

The picture shows the voltage difference between the Triac terminals. I have downloaded st_standard_snubberless_triacs.lib and I have added spice directive.

But, 30 volts (RMS) is lost between the terminals of the Triac. There shouldn't be that much voltage loss. Where is the error?

[image]

Comment: Which points are you probing? I suspect it is just because you don't have the reference coeect. You have the have the load connected to ground. It is easier to understand if you have ground at the bottom.

Comment: @Kevin White I have measured voltage of triac.(one prob is in A1 point,other probe is in A2 point)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like they modelled their triacs with VCSW as the main switch, so probably a behavioural model for speed, but that means the ON resistance is fixed, so the voltage drop is proportional to its value. In addition, the switching is very much dependent on boolean expressions inside the `.subckt` definition, both for the A-K path and the G-K path, which makes this model a not so good one, even if the command is not the brute-force way you've used (separate `PULSE()` source).

---

[Edit]

[Ste Kulov](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/581463/how-do-i-solve-the-triac-error-in-the-ltspice-program/581502?noredirect=1#comment1522939_581502) caught the real error, which is the pin order: the subcircuit uses `A K G`, but the symbol uses `A G K`. With that change (see the dashed rectangle) the result starts out well, but the simulation stalls. My guess is that the behavioural expressions are to blame, however, the solution (or one of them) is to place a `1n` capacitor (`C1`) across the triac:

[image: runs]

Comment: How can I use like real-life triac model?

Comment: @mike_lay944 Do you have one? If yes then you use it in the same manner you would use any model in SPICE (or LTspice, in particular). Otherwise you should know that whatever simulation you want to consider, for whatever device or schematic, it will only give results as good as the models. And models in SPICE are only approximations of their real-life coutnerparts, and only rarely they have a close enough match with the intended device.

Comment: @mike_lay944  Did you guys remember to reshuffle the gate pin of the TRIAC to pin 2?  The ST subcircuit assumes gate is pin 3, but LTspice's symbol in the [Misc] folder assumes the gate is pin 2.

Comment: @SteKulov Oops! That I didn't do, and you are right. That was the cause for the bad waveform. Still, changing the order causes the simulation to stall, and I suspect the boolean expressions to be the culprits. But it can be solved by adding a 1n cap across the triac; that makes it work. You could post an answer, it will be a ton better than mine.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  I'm too lazy.  Haha.  Can you just edit yours?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  Thanks!  You are the champ!  OK, back to nap time...